# Rails 3 send mailer if user attribute is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

I am sending an email whenever a new record is created in my Rails 3 application.

```
def new_resource_notification(resource)
  @resource = resource
  mail(:to => "admin@domain.com", :bcc => User.all.map(&:email), :subject => "New item added")
end
```

**Resource Controller**

```
# POST /resources
  # POST /resources.json
  def create
    @resource = Resource.create( params[:resource] )
    @resource.uploadedip_string = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']

    respond_to do |format|
      if @resource.save

        UserMailer.new_resource_notification(@resource).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to @resource, notice: 'Resource was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @resource, status: :created, location: @resource }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am using Devise for the user authentication an have added a field called `email_subscribe`. I've also added a simple checkbox in the user profile view to enable and disable the subscription.

Everything is working correctly at the moment. All users receive an email when a new record is created and users can set and unset their subscription. What I am trying to do now is make the two work together.

How do I only send an email to the users who's email_subscribe is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mails = User.where(:email_subscriber => true)
mail(:to => "admin@domain.com", :bcc => mails, subject => "New item added")
```